# Qt TableView ChekcBox with Label

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I need to display check box with label in table view cell,  with current code It display the checkbox status instead of label. I have created custom delegate and model. Below is the completed code.

[The result I got look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLd0s.png)

**table_view_delegate.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include "QSpinBox"
#include "QDoubleSpinBox"
#include "QCheckBox"
#include "QApplication"
#include "QStyle"
class table_view_delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     table_view_delegate(QObject *parent = nullptr);
     QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
     void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
     void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,  const QModelIndex &index) const override;
     void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
     void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;


signals:

};
```

**table_view_delegate.cpp**

```
#include "table_view_delegate.h"
#include "QMouseEvent"
#include "QAbstractItemModel"
#include "QCheckBox"
#include "QSpinBox"

table_view_delegate::table_view_delegate(QObject *parent)  : QStyledItemDelegate{parent}
{

}

QWidget *table_view_delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option , const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    int c= index.column();
    if(c == 0 ){
         QCheckBox* check = new QCheckBox("Lable",parent);
         return check;
    }
    else  if(c == 1 ){
        QSpinBox *editor = new QSpinBox(parent);
        return editor;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }

}

void table_view_delegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    int c= index.column();
   if(c == 0 ){
        int value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::CheckStateRole).toInt();
        QCheckBox* check = static_cast<QCheckBox*>(editor);
        if(value==0)
            check->setChecked(false);
        else
            check->setChecked(true);

        check->setText("test");
    }
    else if(c==1){
       QString val_str = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
       float value = val_str.toFloat();
       QDoubleSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
       spinBox->setValue(value);
   }

}

void table_view_delegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,  const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    int c= index.column();
    if(c == 0 ){
        QCheckBox* check = static_cast<QCheckBox*>(editor);
        check->setText("test");
        QString value =QString::number(check->isChecked());//check->isChecked();
        model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);

    }
    else if(c ==1){
        QDoubleSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
        spinBox->interpretText();
        QString value = QString::number(spinBox->value(), 'f', 2);
        model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
    }

}

void table_view_delegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,  const QModelIndex &/* index */) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}

void table_view_delegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

**table_view_model.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class table_view_model : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit table_view_model(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setDataList(QList <QStringList> alog_data_list);
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation ,   int role) const override;

private:
    QList <QStringList> model_data_list;
    int col_count = 3;
    QStringList header={"CheckBox","SpinBox","String"};

signals:

};
```

**table_view_model.cpp**

```
#include "table_view_model.h"

table_view_model::table_view_model(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel{parent}
{

}

int table_view_model::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
   return model_data_list.length();
}

int table_view_model::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return col_count;
}

QVariant table_view_model::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    int r = index.row();
    int c = index.column();

    if(model_data_list.length()==0)
           return QVariant();

     if (!index.isValid())
           return QVariant();

     if( c==0){
         if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole&& c==0 ){
            int checked = model_data_list[r][c].toInt();
            if (checked)
                return Qt::Checked;
            else
               return Qt::Unchecked;
        }
        else if(role == Qt::EditRole){
              return  model_data_list[r][c];
         }
        else if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
              return  model_data_list[r][c];

     }
     else{
       if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            return  model_data_list[r][c];
     }

      return QVariant();

}


bool table_view_model::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
     int c=index.column();
     if(  c==1){
            if (role == Qt::EditRole) {
                if (!checkIndex(index))
                    return false;
                return true;
            }

    }
    else if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole&&c==0)
    {

         model_data_list[index.row()][index.column()] = value.toString();

         if ((Qt::CheckState)value.toInt() == Qt::Checked)
         {
             //user has checked item
             return true;
         }
         else
         {
             //user has unchecked item
             return true;
         }

    }
    return false;
}

void table_view_model::setDataList(QList <QStringList> model_data_listTmp){
    table_view_model::beginResetModel();

    model_data_list.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<model_data_listTmp.length();i++){
        model_data_list.push_back(model_data_listTmp[i]);
    }

    table_view_model::endResetModel();
}


Qt::ItemFlags table_view_model::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    int c=index.column();
    //Editable column
    if(c==1)
        return Qt::ItemIsEditable | QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);
    else if(c==0)
       return Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);
    else
        return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);
}

QVariant table_view_model::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,   int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole){
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
            return header.at(section);
        else
            return QString::number(section);

}
```

In MainWindow.cpp I am initializing the table view like.

```
 table_view_model *model = new table_view_model();
   //QSqlQueryModel *algo_model  = db_conn->getAlgoTableData();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    table_view_delegate *delgate = new table_view_delegate() ;
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(delgate);

    QList <QStringList> data_list;
    QStringList r1;
    r1.append("0");
    r1.append("100");
    r1.append("Str1");
    data_list.append(r1);

    QStringList r2;
    r2.append("1");
    r2.append("200");
    r2.append("Str2");
    data_list.append(r2);

     model->setDataList(data_list);
```

Comment: Do you have anything against the way checkboxes are shown by default in `QTableView`? How about simply using `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegateForColumn` (for the spinbox)?

Comment: I need to apply delegate for different column, so I thought creating a single class and code inside it.

Comment: I keep thinking you can create a delegate for `column 1` and use no delegate at all for `column 0` (+ you can improve reusability of your delegate class by removing the hardcoded references to which columns they are called for). Even if there is something you dislike about the way manages checkboxes by default, it is a better design to define 2 delegates in their own classes.

Comment: Actually I have created some sample code to demonstrate the issue, my original code uses lot of column, the first one is check box with label and  some background color based on the check state. The remaining Colum some column is editable and some are read only.

Comment: Anyway... in `table_view_delegate::setModelData` for column 0, you set data for `Qt::EditRole` instead of `Qt::CheckStateRole` as you correctly do in `table_view_delegate::setEditorData`. My guess is that your bug stems from there (possibly the same confusion about roles occurs in other places)

Comment: I set CheckStateRole in above code for check box right?

Comment: For `column 0` in your sample: `model->setData(index, value, Qt::CheckStateRole);`

Comment: So do I need to change to `model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);` I tested that way too but the label not showing.

Comment: What does it show? a checkbox with no text next to it? And without the delegate?

Comment: With above code it gives. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLd0s.png

Comment: With` model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);` it give same result.

Comment: I searched in internet no solution found for last 2 days.

Comment: You have not answered what it looks like without the delegate...

Comment: Ok sorry I will let you know.

Comment: I got the same result as in the image above I commented the line  `ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(delgate);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a lot of confusion between roles.

Your model seems to need 3 roles. Quick description of them with my words. Make sure to check the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) for the roles I have not described.

- `Qt::DisplayRole`: What shows on screen e.g. a formatted number (actual type `QString`) with its thousand separators.
- `Qt::EditRole`: The underlying data displayed, e.g. the actual number of the model. It is the data you are expected to use in the delegate's editor. In many cases however, the data for `Qt::EditRole` is the same as the data for `Qt::DisplayRole`.
  also, you may choose to implement a model that accepts being  edited in its `Qt::EditRole` and `Qt::DisplayRole`, the difference really is about formatting for screen display.
- `Qt::CheckStateRole`: [Checkstate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#CheckState-enum) (type `Qt::CheckState`) at the index. It is a null `QVariant` by default meaning the view will not show a checkbox.
  However, you can implement a delegate that will show a checkbox in all cases (or oppositely, have a delegate that shows no checkbox even if there should be one)

In your model, you store everything in `QList <QStringList> model_data_list;`

Sample from your `data` method:

```
 if( c==0){
     if (role == Qt::CheckStateRole && c==0){
        int checked = model_data_list[r][c].toInt(); //here, used for Qt::CheckStateRole
        [...]
    }
    else if(role == Qt::EditRole){
          return  model_data_list[r][c]; //here, used for Qt::EditRole
     }
    else if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
          return  model_data_list[r][c]; //here, used for Qt::DisplayRole

 }
```

Then you should not be surprised the text shown is the same as the check state. You must create super clear boundaries between roles as to never run into that confusion.

One easy solution is to add a new member to your class to store check states, then use it in your `data` and `setData` methods. While you are at it, change the type of the other member, there is no need to constantly convert between `QString` and `QVariant`.

In your header:

```
QList <QVariantList> model_data_list; //QVariant is more suitable than QString to store your model's data.
QList<Qt::CheckState> model_checkstate_list; //1-dimensional list as only column 0 has checkstates.
```

With some serious refactoring, your source file becomes:

```
QVariant table_view_model::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    //Try to use auto to get the row and column of index.
    //With any luck, Qt will some day change the return value to be qsizetype of similar.
    //auto will make sure you benefit the change when it happens.
    auto r = index.row(), c = index.column();

    switch (role) {
    case Qt::CheckStateRole: {
        if (c == 0)
            return model_checkstate_list[r];
        else
            return QVariant();
    }
    case Qt::DisplayRole: //We treat Display and Edit roles identically.
    case Qt::EditRole: return value;
    default: return QVariant();
    }
}

bool table_view_model::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    auto r = index.row(), c = index.column();
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::CheckStateRole: {
        if (c == 0) {
            model_checkstate_list[r] = value.value<Qt::CheckState>();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    case Qt::DisplayRole: //We treat Display and Edit roles identically.
    case Qt::EditRole: {
        model_data_list[r][c] = value;
        return true;
    }
    default: return false;
    }
}
```

I am not going to address the delegate because this is not what causes your display issue and after I pointed it out in my comments, I am going to assume you corrected the `setModelData` but I repeat you should seriously consider to have a different delegate for each column of your view. It would remove all the `if (c == 0)` and allow for using the delegate in views/models where checkboxes are not in `column 0`.

Comment: Thanks for taking effort to clear out the problem, I will check it and report back.

Comment: And regarding `have a different delegate for each column` I thought the standard method is having one delegate class and apply to every column. In my real code there are few column editable and few read-only, does it create problem if I create separate delegate for each column. Can I share 1 delegate class for two different column?

Comment: Let me put it this way: if `createEditor` returns a widget of a certain class for a column and a widget of another class for another column, then each columns should get their own specialized delegates, and the delegates should be unaware of any hardcoded rule such as `index.column() == 0`. To give an idea, I have myself implemented a delegate based on `QCheckbox` that has way more code than yours. With your approach, I would be forced to copy all that code to a new class every time I implement a new model.

Comment: Regarding the fact your model has editable columns and read-only columns, this is to be implemented in your model (method `flags`), which you seem to have done correctly already.

Comment: In any case, your model should work even when you put no delegates onto the view and your delegates should not have to be aware of any specificities of your model in order to work. Read mode about coupling [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). Quote: "Low coupling is often thought to be a sign of a well-structured computer system and a good design"

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts. It helped me to understand more about qt model-view programing.